# How to update React-Query data after socket signal?

Tags: react-query

I have app using React-Query, and I need to trigger data update after socket signal. That is, if I am on the user's page and I received a notification that the user's data has changed, then I need to send a request to receive updated data and write it. How to listen to socket events using useQuery hook?

Comment: react-query has nothing to do with (web)sockets so you would need to manually implement it on your side (or use some other library)

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't do that with useQuery, but you would setup a socket subscription separately and then either write to the cache when you receive a message, or just invalidate the query to trigger a refetch.

I have a full blog post on this topic:
https://tkdodo.eu/blog/using-web-sockets-with-react-query

But the gist is:

```
const useReactQuerySubscription = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const websocket = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org/')
    websocket.onopen = () => {
      console.log('connected')
    }
    websocket.onmessage = (event) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(event.data)
      const queryKey = [...data.entity, data.id].filter(Boolean)
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(queryKey)
    }

    return () => {
      websocket.close()
    }
  }, [queryClient])
}
```